# Office365 AADSTS50034 error

Tags: azure, office365

We use azure multi-tenant app, to access our users Office365 calendars. It works fine, but for some users (1%) we get Oauth2 AADSTS50034 error:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50034: To sign into this application the account must be added to the <user_domain> directory","error_codes":[50034]}
```

What does it really mean and how to fix it?